# Get all types referenced by the given type with roslyn

Tags: c#, roslyn

I want to get the types that current type is referencing, just like in Visual Studio code map "Show the types this references".
I can load solution, find the project and get the symbol for my type of interest. And at this point I'm stuck. Can't find any example or documentation, how to get symbols from the given symbol.

The overall task if following: I have a really big legacy solution. I need to take some functionality from it to the new one. I find the key class, then I take it to my new solution. Of course there are lots of references which I have to resolve manually. I want to use roslyn to get the list of all references for a class and take them in one step to the new solution.

Comment: Do you need it to be recursive to check the types used by the types returned by the first layer searched?

Comment: In the final version yes. But I think recursive is not the problem :) If I get the immediate references I can do the same call for them.

Comment: Could not achieve what I wanted via Roslyn. But had success with NRefactory. NRefactory also is 2-3 times faster to load solution with ~30 projects and 5500+ types.